# Can't install JWT via composer

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm trying to install JWT in laravel but after a while I get this error.
I had installed it before but I had to remove it (using composer remove) because I was not using it

Img: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2H5F.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says

> Target class [auth] does not exist

Make sure you have that correct in your current Laravel code, check for any residues, doesn't need to be in JWT it can be in your own app code, nonetheless that's where you want to start from.

---

#### More to that

The issue isn't in the installation i believe, as the error is coming after `php artisan package:discover` i believe that if you do `composer dump-autoload` you will get the same error even without installing that package, try that, if that's the case, then it's surely somewhere in your app code

Comment: Yes, it gives me the same error... Is there a way to find the error in the code?

Comment: It's a matter of debugging now, you need to search for auth class in your code, check laravel logs at /storage/log and follow the stacks it should lead you to where it's being used,

Comment: my best friend here is my IDE phpStorm (ctrl+f5) search for auth and look through the list whatever is in my /app directory or any directory that is not from vendors, takes few seconds to find it

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your composer.lock file on the root directory of the project and try again.

Hope it helps!